# Solved: What's the equivalent of Aspose.Pdf.Kit.PdfPrivilege in the "merged" version of Aspose (6.x)

Tags: aspose

I am migrating a project how to replace this class.

Aspose documentation says that the Aspose.Pdf.kit namespace has migrated to Aspose.Pdf.Facades, but there is not Aspose.Pdf.Facades.PdfPrivilege

Any clues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissing setting has changed and is now supposed to be done with this class: Aspose.Pdf.Facades.DocumentPrivilege